# PHP - calling array value from method that returns it?

Tags: php, arrays, object, methods, associative-array

I'm trying to call an array variable directly from a method that returns it.  Something like the following:

```
function some_meth()
{
    return array('var1' => 'var);
}
```

I know I can do something like this:

```
$var = some_meth();
$var = $var['var1'];
```

But I would like to be able to do this in one line, something like this:

```
$var = some_meth()['var1'];
```

This returns the error below, which makes sense, but is there a way to do this in one line?

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Answer (score 4):

In pre-php5.4 this is not possible in a single call. 5.4 on you can accomplish it just like in your example.

From http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

```
<?php
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];

// or
list(, $secondElement) = getArray();
?>
```

Comment: hmm, okay, I guess I'll have to stick with the old school way for now, we're still on 5.3.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in new 5.4 version, released 1 March

More information [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing?s%5B%5D=array&s%5B%5D=dereferencing)